# Plotting points over box plot in PlotlyJS Julia

Tags: plot, julia, boxplot, plotly.js

I would like to plot data points over a box plot in `PlotlyJS` in Julia. Here is some reproducible code to create a box plot with data points side by side:

```
using PlotlyJS, CSV, DataFrames
df = dataset(DataFrame, "tips")
PlotlyJS.plot(df, x=:time, y=:total_bill, boxpoints="all", kind="box")
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it nicely plots the data points and box plot side by side, but I would like to add the point on top of the box plot. In plotly python we may use `stripmode = "overlay"`, but this doesn't work for PlotlyJS. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add the points on top of the box plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `pointpos=0`:

```
julia> using PlotlyJS, RDatasets, DataFrames

julia> df = RDatasets.dataset("datasets", "iris")[!, 1:4];

julia> PlotlyJS.plot(df, x=:PetalLength, y=:SepalWidth, boxpoints="all", kind="box", pointpos=0)
```

[image]

---

I would like to add the answer to the provided dataset in the question to show the expected result (@Shayan of course found the answer!):

```
using PlotlyJS, CSV, DataFrames
df = dataset(DataFrame, "tips")
PlotlyJS.plot(df, x=:time, y=:total_bill, boxpoints="all", kind="box", pointpos=0)
```

Output:

[image]